# Perl: color error log with specific character

Tags: html, perl

how to color the output with specific string/character, like if the log contains word "ERROR", it will be RED, "Warning" will be yellow and "Info" will be green in PERL

Comment: color it to what kind of output?  printer?  terminal?  what OS?

Comment: sorry for not being in details, an error log output in browser in windows box

Comment: `<FONT COLOR="######">text text text text text</FONT>`

Comment: What is it with all these people suggesting <font> tags? It's 2013, people. <font> tags haven't been the best solution for well over ten years.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are going to output this to a web browser you could use:

```
$logfile = "/var/log/log.txt" ;
open INFILE, "$logfile" ; 
@loglines = <INFILE> ; 
close INFILE;

foreach $line (@loglines) {
   if ($line =~ /ERROR/) {
      $line = "<span style=\"color: red;\">" . $line . "</span>";
     }
   elsif ($line =~ /Warning/) {
     $line = "<span style=\"color: yellow;\">" . $line . "</span>";
     }
   elsif ($line =~ /Info/) {
     $line = "<span style=\"color: green;\">" . $line . "</span>";
     }
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're generating HTML, it seems to me that it would be a good option to apply classes to your elements, such as `info`, `warning`, `error`, which you then style using CSS.

How do you set a class? That all depends on what you're using to generate HTML. If you're just printing raw text, `<span class="info">...</span>` will do the trick. If you're using a DOM builder, you can probably pass it in as a hash argument somewhere or other.

How do you apply a CSS stylesheet? I Googled "css text color" and picked [this tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/colors/article.php/3479011) out of the 10 million results.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to color HTML output (eg output lines like `<FONT COLOR="red">Error!</FONT>`)...or display error messages in the terminal in color?

If the latter, you can do something like this, which will display the text 'error message' in bold, red.

```
use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', 'Win32::Console::ANSI';
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
print BOLD, RED, "error message\n", RESET;
```